# Adding comments to image

Tags: asp.net, webforms, comments

i am trying to add comments to the images in my website in asp. net, using c#. I am using gridview for the images, and i add new text-box file in the grid for inserting comments. I add one table named ImageComments with CommentID, UserId, Body and id_image. Here is my code.

```
 protected void addReviewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
        string connectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string insertSql = "INSERT INTO ImageComments(Body, UserId) VALUES(@Body, @UserId)";
        TextBox reviewTextBox = GridView1.FindControl("reviewTextBox1") as TextBox;

        string a = reviewTextBox.Text;

            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Body", a);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", currentUserId);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection.Close();
            }

            reviewTextBox.Text = string.Empty;

        }

    }
```

I  got the famous error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I think I have problem with the method FindControl(), becouse I don't have problems with it when the TextBox (the comment file ) in outside of the grid. I am stuck with this error about one week. Please, place, if anyone know somthing, help me

Comment: What line does the error focuses on?

Comment: It's on this line  string a = reviewTextBox.Text;

Answer (score 1):

When you have problem with the reviewTextBox you can try code below to find the textbox in the gridview

```
Button button = sender as Button;
TextBox reviewTextBox = button.NamingContainer.FindControl("reviewTextBox1") as TextBox;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) I have one more question. I am using gridview to display the data. I have a text box file in the gridview for inserting comments under every image. I have table where i store the data about the comment (CommentId, UserId, id_image, body), but i don't know how to get the value from id_image column in gridview. Can syou help me?